# select all divs where the difference only on the middle number of ID

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have all these divs with an identical ID name except for the fact that they all have a different number in the middle.

```
   <div id="myid1region">text</div>
     <div id="myid20region">text</div>
     <div id="myid333region">text</div>
     <div id="myid4region">text</div>
```

How to select all divs by css?

```
div#myid[*]region {  }
```

I don't wanna get this `<div id="myid[numbers]region.read">text</div>` in the result group

Comment: what you want exactly??

Comment: Here you go: [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: why dont use  `div[id^="myid"]{ }` ?

Comment: @ehsan, you just edited in that OP wants to exclude `id=myid333region`, but where do you take that from? I don't see OP saying that anywhere.

Comment: @domdom, Shakirov Ramil send for you a comment and he said what he want,because mark my answer.i dont mark my answer.

Comment: The comment, which OP deleted shortly after, clarified that he wanted to exlude `id`s like `myid333region.read` (in other words, `id`s that end in `region.read`, as OPs own edit to the question clarified). I guess OP needs to clarify once again...

Comment: @domdom , My goal is to help others no gain points.

Comment: @ehsan: Who said anything about points? You seem to be the only one harping on the fact that your answer was downvoted yet marked accepted. It's your own fault for posting an answer knowing you were unsure what was being asked - instead of voting to close the question as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```css
div[id^="myid"][id$="region"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myid1region">text</div>
<div id="myid2region">text</div>
<div id="myid3region.read">text</div>
<div id="myid4region">text</div>
```

**Explanation** from the MDN docs on `[attr$=value]`:

> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr the value of which is suffixed by "value".

In other words, with this you will match all `id`s that end in `region`. This excludes `id`s that end in `region.read`, as you desire.

If you have other `id`s ending in `region`, but *not* starting with `myid`, you can make your selector more explicit, matching only those `id`s that *start* with `myid` and *end* in `region`:

```
div[id^="myid"][id$="region"] { ... }
```